# SQL query to identify patterns in Parent-Child relationship

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with an Oracle database in a financial institution.  It has a Credit Facility table and a Loan table, in a parent-child relationship (1-many).

As part of a project, they added a new field called Type Code to both of these tables (using some complex logic involving the values of a bunch of other fields).  I assumed that in the vast majority of cases the parent Credit Facility and all of the children Loans would be assigned the same Type Code.  But it turns out that there are hundreds of thousands of cases where the Credit Facility and the Loan have different Type Codes, and all those cases have to be "handled" somehow.  I was able to make a query to generate a list of all the Credit Facilities and related Loans where 1 or more Loans have a different Type Code from its parent, and the result was 600K records.

Results look like this (Simplified)

[image: example 1]

Now I want to break it down into patterns, hopefully using 1 field that I can group by.  The field should have values like below:

[image: example 2]

The Pattern field should always generate the same value based on the parent's Type Code and the unique values of the children.  I don't care how many child Loans there are of each type or what order they come in.

Any ideas for how to generate this PATTERN field in a SQL query?  I could also do it in Excel in a pinch, but not even sure how to do that, short of writing VBA code, which is my last resort.

Thank you!

Comment: For 789, why the pattern is A - A, followed by B,C? Why is it not C - A and B,C?

Comment: What is the expected output, if it possible to have the following case?`SELECT 789, 'C', 78901, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 789, 'C', 78902, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 789, 'C', 78903, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 789, 'C', 78904, 'D' FROM DUAL union all
select 789, 'C', 78905, 'D' from dual`

Comment: Where does the "A" come from at the beginning of the pattern?

Comment: sorry, my error.  For 789 the pattern should be C - A,B,C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will produce the results you want, assuming you rename your TYPE fields so they're distinct from one another - one should probably be FACILITY_TYPE and the other should apparently be LOAN_TYPE:

```
WITH cteDistinct_facility_loan_types
       AS (SELECT DISTINCT FACILITY_NUM,
                  LOAN_TYPE
             FROM YOUR_TABLE),
     cteFacility_loan_types
       AS (SELECT FACILITY_NUM,
                  LISTAGG(LOAN_TYPE, ',')
                    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FACILITY_NUM) AS FACILITY_LOAN_TYPES
             FROM cteDistinct_facility_loan_types
             GROUP BY FACILITY_NUM)
SELECT t.*,
       t.FACILITY_TYPE || '-' || flt.FACILITY_LOAN_TYPES AS PATTERN
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
  INNER JOIN cteFacility_loan_types flt
    ON flt.FACILITY_NUM = t.FACILITY_NUM
  ORDER BY t.FACILITY_NUM
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5b7f6c80dbd6aa5cab3ca6906892f1a0)

Comment: awesome!  I wasn't aware of LISTAGG, it's exactly what I need.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to look at the patterns for the facilities, then you can use `listagg()` as an analytic function:

```
select t.*,
       (t.facility_num || '-' ||
        listagg(t.loan_type, ',') within group (order by loan_num) over (partition by facility_num)
       ) as pattern
from t;
```

These results are a bit different from what you have.  They start with the facility type and they include *all* loans, including duplicates.

If you want the distinct `loan_type`s, then use a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (t.facility_num || '-' ||
        listagg(case when seqnum = 1 then t.loan_type end, ',') within group
            (order by loan_num) over
            (partition by facility_num)
       ) as pattern
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by facility_num, loan_type order by loan_num) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=349703328a15008d856e169051aab9a0) is a db<>fiddle.